How to model rolled up money?
So I am trying to model a fat roll of money. I got the first part down of 1 bill but can't get the rest. I used array and curve modifiers for the first one, its not working the way I want for other bills using modifiers. I tried manually but it won't work. I used an image as a plane, subdivided it, and added the said modifiers.
Here's the reference
This is what I got so far 
Thank you!

Do you need to model each bill ? Or can you use a texture, perhaps with a displacement map, for the sides ?

Something like this?

I made a rolled plane with path curve, converted it to mesh and extruded.
Then added an empty and applied array modifier to the roll with "object offset" checked, and selected that empty as an offset object. Slightly rotate empty on z axis and scale it down on x and y axis'

